# SQL Error Creating alias for DATEPART() or YEAR()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

does anybody know why I might be getting an error when trying to create an alias for DATEPART() or YEAR()?

In order to run the query I had to type the whole DATEPART() function (got same error if tried to use YEAR():

```
SELECT TOP 3 ShipCountry,DATEPART(year,orderdate), AvgFreight=AVG(freight)
FROM orders
WHERE DATEPART(year,orderdate)='2015' 
Group by ShipCountry, DATEPART(year,orderdate)
Order by AvgFreight desc
```

---

I tried to do:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ShipCountry,OrdersByYear=DATEPART(year,orderdate), AvgFreight=AVG(freight)
FROM orders
WHERE OrdersByYear='2015' 
Group by ShipCountry, OrdersByYear
Order by AvgFreight desc
```

ERROR was:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'OrdersByYear'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'OrdersByYear'.

Didn't got that error with AVG alias, Thank you!

Comment: Tag your question with the databse you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias is fine.  You just can't use aliases in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ShipCountry, DATEPART(year,orderdate) as orderyear,
       AVG(freight) as  AvgFreight
FROM orders
WHERE orderDate >= '2015-01-01' and orderDate < '2016-01-01'
Group by ShipCountry, DATEPART(year, orderdate)
Order by AvgFreight desc;
```

Note that it is not needed in the `group by` for this query, because you are only looking at one year:

```
select TOP 3 ShipCountry, max(datepart(year, orderdate)) as orderyear,
       AVG(freight) as  AvgFreight
from orders
where orderDate >= '2015-01-01' and orderDate < '2016-01-01'
Group by ShipCountry
Order by AvgFreight desc;
```

Note that I changed the date comparisons in the `where` clause.  This makes it easier for the optimizer to produce a better query plan.

Comment: Thank you very much!! seems easier using a range of date on the Where function.